# Define ContextMenu in Default Style Throws FallbackControl Exception in Designer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In an attempt to embrace xaml bindings, I've attempted to move my context menu into a default style.  I use commands in my menu items which work great, however, when I attempt to load a page that contains one of these controls I get an exception in the designer.  How can I prevent this exception from occurring?

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Controls:customObject}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
        <Setter.Value>
           <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}">
                <MenuItem Header="Open" Command="{Binding customObjectController.open, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Designer Exception:

> ArgumentException: 'Microsoft.Expression.Platform.InstanceBuilders.FallbackControl' is not a valid value for the 'System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenuService.ContextMenu' property on a Setter.